# referencing sphinx generated Python docs from YAML file

Tags: python-sphinx

We have an internal python API that we have documented using Sphinx. part of the system uses YAML for configuration files that contain reference to py file that use the API. I've been asked to see if there is a way, using sphinx, to link the YAML config files to the the appropriate API docs. I've been doing research on google, here  and sphinx site and it looks like I may be able to use intersphinx but I'm unclear how to make the connection between the two.

so for example: here is the yaml config file:

```
HALT_LEVEL: Any
SUITE: "Checkin Tests"
DESCRIPTION: "checkin test suite"

TESTLIST:
    - TESTCASE: install stuff
      DESC: "Installs RPM"
      TESTGROUP: sprint_0
      TESTFILE: install_stuff.py   # I would like to turn this into a link to our sphinx docs
                                   # for this. This file is already part of sphinx docs"
```

So then when someone is looking at the html/sphinx version of the the above file they could click on install_stuff.py and it take them to the docs that exist

Is this possible?

thanks in advance,
Greg.

Answer (score 1):

Just for those that may be interested. I was able to do this but not using Sphinx. I used pyyaml to read the file and pygments to generate the html then hacked the generated html.

Since pygments doesn't appear to allow live href links what to add them what I is

```
# create a yaml string using pyyaml and then modify the string.
href = '[ahref="%s"]%s[/a]' % (hrefData, hrefString)
yamldata['KEYWORD'][idx]['HOST'] = href
```

This changes the referenced yaml to a string that looks something like `'[ahref="http://example.com"]Example.com[/a]'`. The brackets make it easier to change after the html is generated. Further down in the code I use pygments to generate the html

```
htmlpage = highlight(yamldata,lexer, HtmlFormatter(full=True, title=yamldata['TITLE']))
```

Now I convert the href that I created above to a real href with:

```
webpage = htmlpage.replace('&#39;', '').replace('ahref', 'a href').replace('[','<').replace(']','>').replace('&quot;','"')
```